# Почему PyCharm не подсвечивает ошибки при написании python кода?

Tags: pycharm

У меня такой вопрос: Почему PyCharm не подсвечивает ошибки при написании python кода?
Я их вижу только после запуска внизу на терминале.

К примеру написал не `print` а `prient`. Или отступ сделал не так. Когда я пробую специально сделать ошибку, чтобы её увидеть, никакой реакции, только после запуска. Какой плагин за это отвечает, не могу найти

Comment: о каких ошибках речь?

Comment: Ну к примеру написал не print а prient. Или отступ сделал не так. Когда я пробую специально сделать ошибку, чтобы её увидеть, никакой реакции, только после запуска. Какой плагин за это отвечает, не могу найти.

Comment: Проверьте, что не включен Power save mode (в меню File)

Answer (score 1):

Меню `File` -> `Settings...` -> `Editor` -> `Inspections` (или нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, там нужно выбрать профиль по умолчанию (Default). Этого должно хватить. Или же можно более тонко настроить разную подсветку ошибок для разных языков и разных типов ошибок.

Конкретно за подсветку `prient` вместо `print` отвечает Unresoled references.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужно понимать, что подсвечиваются не все ошибки. К примеру, `prient` вместо `print` не будет подсвечиваться, если у вас действительно есть функция `prient`.

Так же и неправильные (с точки зрения логики программы) отступы могут не подсвечиваться, если синтаксически они верны.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Всем за терпение и пожелания. Я тут же нашёл ответ на свою проблему:

Мне помогло снятие галки с пункта File Menu -> Power Saver Mode
Всем Удачи!!!